# Dynamic menu tabs in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking to achieve a UI setup along this lines: (http://designrope.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/dashboard-ui-4.png)

That is, there is a double menu - the one on the left is a dynamic tab type menu where an item is added if after a certain event in the application (e.g. a user adds something), and then a main menu ,that organises and renders the information associated with each tab. Menu tab is also removable so if an event takes place which gets rid of the information associated with the specific tab, the menu tab disappears.

Having researched I'm still unsure as to what would be the best way to achieve this in ReactJS?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need data that represents the state of the app, eg:

```
const state = {
  activeAccount: 1,
  activeTab: "settings",
  accounts: [
    { name: "...", 
      type: "facebook", 
      buffer: { ... }, 
      analytics: { ... }, 
      schedule:  { ... },
      settings: { ... } },
    { name: "...", 
      type: "twitter", 
      buffer: { ... }, 
      analytics: { ... }, 
      schedule:  { ... },
      settings: { ... }},
    { name: "...", 
      type: "...", 
      buffer: { ... }, 
      analytics: { ... }, 
      schedule:  { ... },
      settings: { ... }}];
```

Then organize your components is the same way:

```
const App = function({ accounts, activeAccount }) {
  return (
   <div className="app">
    <div className="accounts">
      {accounts.map(account => (
        <a href="#" onClick={...}>
          {account.name}
        </a>)}
    </div>
    <div className="tabs">
      {accounts[activeAccount].buffer && (
        <a href="#" onClick={...}>Buffer</a>)}
      {accounts[activeAccount].analytics && (
        <a href="#" onClick={...}>Analytics</a>)}
      {accounts[activeAccount].schedule && (
        <a href="#" onClick={...}>Schedule</a>)}
      {accounts[activeAccount].settings && (
        <a href="#" onClick={...}>Setting</a>)}
    </div>
    <div className="content">
      { ... some content based on active account and active tab ... }
    </div>
  </div>);

}
```

I would recommend to use `react-router` for managing active account and tabs states.

Comment: @AloeVeraForty I cannot remember any react UI libraries that look like your image. I think you have to stylize the components yourself via CSS

Comment: So in the example you provide, the html <a> tag would be replaced with link from react-router e.g. <Link to= />. jsfiddle would help really help clarify..

Comment: I know this is an old post but here's a very nice UI Framework for React projects - Semantic UI (https://react.semantic-ui.com/)